# Buscar Módulos de acordo com as Permissões

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Elaborei uma função que lista todos os módulos e submódulos dentro do sistema. Mas eu preciso que seja diferente, preciso que nesta mesma listagem, só venha os módulos e submodulos que o cliente tem acesso, ao invés de fazer a verificação se ele tem permissão ou não. Vou expor como eu fiz:

Função para Listagem dos Módulos:

```
public function getModulosCategoria(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM modulos WHERE idModuloBase = '0'";
    $consulta = $this->db->query($sql)->result();   

        foreach($consulta as &$valor){
            $sql_model = "SELECT * FROM modulos WHERE idModuloBase = '{$valor->idModulo}'";
            $valor->subModulo = $this->db->query($sql_model)->result();     
        }

    return $consulta;
}
```

Na listagem faço a seguinte verificação:

```
foreach($modulo->subModulo as $submodulo){
    $permissao = "a".ucfirst($submodulo->pasta);
    if($this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),$permissao)){
         Exibe o Link para o Modulo...
```

Até ai está funcionando 100%, mas eu preciso fazer isto diferente. Quero que ao listar todos os módulos, só busque os módulos permitidos.

Tabela de Modulos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela de Permissões:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorno do campo permissoes dentro da tabela permissões:

```
a:12:{i:0;s:9:"aCedentes";i:1;s:9:"eCedentes";i:2;s:9:"dCedentes";i:3;s:9:"vCedentes";i:4;s:9:"aUsuarios";i:5;s:9:"eUsuarios";i:6;s:9:"dUsuarios";i:7;s:9:"vUsuarios";i:8;s:13:"aFornecedores";i:9;s:13:"eFornecedores";i:10;s:13:"dFornecedores";i:11;s:13:"vFornecedores";}
```

Setar os modulos de cada cliente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa mudar sua query para buscar os módulos relacionando com a tabela permissões. Então retornará a lista de módulos com acesso a um determinado usuário por exemplo.

Mas não vejo uma ligação entre a tabela módulos e a tabela permissões.

Também não consegui visualizar seu json.

Comment: Tenho a impressão que você deveria utilizar os comentários, ao invés de usar a opção "resposta" para isso.

Comment: Exato, porque a permissão é gravada separada... Eu gravo dentro da tabela permissão, como se eu criasse vários tipos de permissões, e ai só seleciono qual a permissão em que o cliente tem... Mas consegui resolver a questão de forma diferente.

Comment: Usaria, mas ainda n posso comentar na pergunta, n sei dizer o por que mas me diz que preciso de 50 pontos.

Comment: Ue, se resolveu posta sua resposta e marca sua resposta como certa. Alguem pode ter a mesma duvida. Desculpem a falta dos acentos.